# Razor reference for VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

MVC 3 is great but in some cases I am having trouble translating the Razor syntax. Anyone know of a good VB.Net Razor reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [good resource](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic) you might take a look at.